# Standard deviation growth of discrete Brownian motion?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, white-noise, brownian-motion

In my current project, I have a collection of $N$ i.i.d. samples of a multivariate standard Gaussian distribution in $D$-dimensional space. My ultimate goal is to gradually perturb the standard Gaussian samples without biasing the summary statistics ($\mu=0$, $\sigma=1$ or $\Sigma=\mathbb{I}$ ) of the distribution. I imagine one way to achieve this is to implement a single step of Brownian motion / addition of small white noise with noise standard deviation $\sigma_{noise}$ to each sample, then re-scaling the resulting ensemble of samples back to a standard univariate Gaussian.

I could do this numerically by simply estimating the standard deviation along each of the $D$ dimensions, then re-normalizing the ensemble. This would make my ensemble "too Gaussian", though, as a finite ensemble of particles won't reproduce the standard deviation of its distribution perfectly.

I imagine that there must be a more formal way to quantify the standard deviation increase during the addition of white noise to standard normal samples, then compensate this theoretical increase. Do you know if and how this standard deviation increase for discrete Brownian motion is calculated?

Comment: Please tell us what the "summary statistics" are.  There are so many possibilities that they uniquely determine the sample and no perturbations are possible.  Indeed, since your question is about samples, why is the manner of their generation (multivariate Gaussian) of any relevance?

Comment: The summary statistics of a standard multivariate Gaussian distribution are of course a mean of zero and a diagonal covariance matrix with a standard deviation of one. The fact that my samples are drawn from a multivariate Gaussian is relevant because the perturbation would otherwise risk corrupting any higher-order moments the samples might have. If you add white noise to a distribution long enough and it will eventually become Gaussian. If the term "samples from" confuses you, replace it mentally with "Monte Carlo approximation of".

Comment: There are many, many more summary statistics, so your limited recitation doesn't merit "of course." The higher-order moments are summary statistics, too.  This has become clearer in light of your edits, but be careful, because most readers will assume "$\mu,$" "$\Sigma,$" and "$\sigma$" are *parameters* of the underlying distribution rather than properties of the sample.  And, once again, the Gaussian assumption is irrelevant. All that matters is that $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are mathematically feasible summary statistics of a multivariate dataset.